# How to put my DB connection outside the .war file?

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I have a web application in Java that runs on Apache Tomcat 7 and at some point does the following connection into a database:

```
    DBConnection database = new DBConnection(
       "user", "password", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433"
       );

    database.connect();

    Connection conn = database.getConn();
```

`DBConnection` is a class I made that has some code about the DB, nothing special (it has the JDBC driver and all). What we can see here is a working connection from Java to a SQLServer DB.

My question is when I generate the `.war`, if I want to quickly change to another DB...I basically can't! (not without having to change these lines to the respective DB and generate a whole new .war).

I wanted to have a quick way of changing into different DBs, apparently what I need to use is `JNDI` context with `DataSource` and create a `Resource` that will be the DB connection...and then if I want to change a DB just change the parameters of the `Resource`.

The question is I can't find a working tutorial that fits my problem...and I've been trying for hours. The maximum point I've got was having a `NoInitialContextException`, but I searched for this error in the web and I can't seem to find a correct explanation.

If someone could shed light into my problem I would be much appreciated.

PS: Sorry for bad English or formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Data Source in your server. Here are the [steps](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+an+Oracle+Datasource+in+Apache+Tomcat).

You will get the connection using below JNDI Look up:

```
private DataSource getDataSource (String dataSourceLocation) throws NamingException
  {
    // Get a context for the JNDI look up
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");

    // Look up a data source
    javax.sql.DataSource ds
      = (javax.sql.DataSource) envContext.lookup (dataSourceLocation); 

    return ds;
  }

  private Connection getConnection (DataSource ds) throws SQLException
  {
    Connection conn = null;
    // Get a connection object
    conn = ds.getConnection();

    return conn;
  }
```

Note: The dataSouceLocation would be "jdbc/UCPPool".

Comment: The link you provided saved me! Simple and straight to the point. Thanks. Question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Put connection information in a property file, and replace your hard-coded values with references to properties. A better approach is to use a framework for all this, like Spring Data:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

This tutorial shows you how to do this in the context.xml file which you can configure Apache Tomcat to reread:

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/configuring-spring-mvc-jdbctemplate-with-jndi-data-source-in-tomcat

Comment: Can even wrap the properties lookup with a reset() method so no need to restart the app.

Comment: @Jan Nielsen I don't wanna use Spring Data as it's something I need just for a quick "new feature" fix for the "client" that asked me this. I don't wanna sound dumb but I at some point was using this: http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/configuring-jndi-datasource-for-database-connection-pooling-in-tomcat which is what I want but what I can't seem to do.

Comment: That seems reasonable enough, @Vitz - add all your code so we can help you spot the error...

Comment: @JanNielsen Question answered, I just needed to change the `server.xml` in the Apache Tomcat and add a few lines into the `web.xml` inside my web project. Thanks for your time and answer! PS: I was putting some code in the wrong .xml files, that was my problem.